Movie about a guy with a Macintosh that he can comunicate with vocally
I saw this movie in the early 90s.
Color, English, USA.
The protagonist has a Mac that has a face of a man. This man talks back and forth to his owner.
At some point, the protagonist tries to access another computer (owned by a villain organization) and, in retaliation, they hack into his Mac and cause it to malfunction. This, of course, causes him to break down emotionally since he is very attached to the talking software on his mac.
One of his friends helps by opening the Mac and doing some electronic fixing which causes the Mac to work again.
That's as much as I remember...

Are you absolutely sure it was a Macintosh computer? I don't suppose it was the 1988 remake of The Absent-Minded Professor? I haven't seen it but it's the only film I've found with a voice-address Macintosh.

@Catija the clip contains 2 seconds of the talking computer, but it was enough for me to confirm it. Please answer so that I can accept.

Awesome! Glad I found it for you!  I'll post an answer shortly!

I believe you're looking for the 1988 remake of The Absent-Minded Professor. It was aired in the US as part of the TV series Walt Disney's Wonderful World of Color.
Here's a promo clip that includes the talking Macintosh computer (at 40 seconds in):



